# Saving Matrices/Lists as Strings

Tags: matrix, string-manipulation

I would like to save `.txt` file with string matrices, possibly doing some string replacement the matrices delimiters and arranging output for symbolic expressions. For example:

```
matrix = {{a,b1 b2},{c1/c2,d}}
```

And I would like to output this to a txt file in the format

```
"((a,b1*b2),(c1/c2,d))"
```

Output is more crucial here since I can replace it later using some other tool, but I would assume replacing such strings would also be easy from within Mathematica? Also I reckon that the "space" representation of multiplicatoin might be a bit tricky?

Thanks

Comment: It would help to know what you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The essence of this method is to realize that `InputForm` matches quite well your desired format. This format is supported by `ToString`, so both

```
ToString[b1 b2, InputForm]
```

> b1*b2

and

```
ToString[c1/c2, InputForm]
```

> c1/c2

work as desired. Hence one way is:

```
matrix = {{a,b1 b2},{c1/c2,d}};
stringmatrix = 
 StringReplace[ToString[matrix, InputForm], {"{" -> "(", "}" -> ")"}]
```

> ((a, b1*b2), (c1/c2, d))

```
Export["matrix.txt", stringmatrix]
```

Note that this will contain whitespaces, so you might want to delete those. You can do this by adding `Whitespace -> ""` to the list of replacement rules in `StringReplace`.

Comment: Ok thanks, this works but I guess my example wasnt general enough...what if I have symbolic fractions in my expressions and I would like those to display with forward slash, say "a/b"?

Comment: Please edit your questions so that it actually contains what you want to know... I can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I have edited it. Many thanks.

Comment: Please see my edit.